# Which design pattern is good for creating an object from modular sub-pieces?

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I want to make a custom button from scratch:

- **BasicButton : NSObject**
  So I created a class which knows how to handle mouse events and forward messages to interested receivers when the button is clicked (via delegation, target/action, notifications, whatever).
- **SolidColorButton : BasicButton : NSObject**
  My button now works but it's invisible, so I decided to draw a solid background to bring the button to life (not very good in terms of UI design but let's pretend).
- **LabelledButton : SolidColorButton : BasicButton : NSObject**
  Now let's say I want to add a label on the button, so I've created a another subclass that can draw text on the button.

So now I have a button which can handle mouse events, draws a solid background, and draws some text. But what happens now if I decide I need a button with an image for a background instead of the solid color, but that still knows how to draw a label? This is where the single-inheritance subclassing approach fails. I can't combine the mouse handling, label drawing and image drawing at will, I can only choose a level of refinement down the inheritance chain.

So I guess my question is: **What's the way to implement these separate modules so that they can then be mixed and matched to create some sort of *offspring* object which has the combined features of the desired modules and nothing else?**

Example, I'd want to be able to write modules like:

- *Mouse handling*
- *Keyboard handling*
- *Solid background*
- *Image background*
- *Label*
- etc.

and then have the ability to to make a specific button which: a) handles mouse, b) draws a background and c) has a label; and nothing else.

The question is specific to how one would do this in Objective-C or another single-inheritance OOP language. In Ruby a way to do this would be using mixins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already noticed that inheritance is a bad idea here. The [**Decorator Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) would come in handy: you will have one button class and several decorators that "decorate" the button (wrap it and add functionality) and can be combined arbitrarily.

**Class diagram:**

```
 +---------------+     innerButton
 |ButtonInterface+------------------------+
 +---------------+ 1                      |
        ^    ^                            |
        |    |                            |
        |    +-------------+              |
 +------+------+   +-------+-------+      |
 | BasicButton |   |ButtonDecorator+------+
 +-------------+   +---------------+
                     ^           ^
                     |           |  ...
                     |           |
+--------------------+----+ +----+------------------+
|SolidColorButtonDecorator| |LabelledButtonDecorator|  ...
+-------------------------+ +-----------------------+
```

**Object diagram (for your example):**

```
+----------------------------+
|MouseHandlingButtonDecorator|
+-----+----------------------+
      |
     1| innerButton
+-----+-------------------+
|BackgroundButtonDecorator|
+-----+-------------------+
      |
     1| innerButton
+-----+-----------------+
|LabelledButtonDecorator|
+-----+-----------------+
      |
     1| innerButton
+-----+-----+
|BasicButton|
+-----------+
```

Comment: +1. You can check the VisualWorks Smalltalk GUI framework implementation, which uses this approach.

Comment: +1 I have use the decorator pattern for code functuonality, not graphical, interface, your answer, makes me have to study more about it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the composition design pattern, yet, modified to look like the "Decorator Pattern".

The following example only applies to the drawing behavior, not the mouse or keyboard behavior. Ignore the dots, in the following chart.

Note: its more like C++ or C#, please ignore the minor differences with objective-c.

First, you want a button class that will "delegate" the "draw" functuonality to members or items. Let's show the main class, by itself, first.

```
................................................................................
..+--------------------------------+..../|..+--------------------------------+..
..|        GraphicObjectClass      |.../.|..|      CompositeButtonClass      |..
..+--------------------------------*--<..|--*--------------------------------+..
..| [+]  void Draw(); <<virtual>>  |...\.|..| [+]  void Draw(); <<override>> |..
..+--------------------------------+....\|..+--------------------------------+..
................................................................................
```

Let's suppose you want a button, and:

- a "module class" that draws a border
- a "module class" that draws the background, wheter solid color, or pattern
- a "module class" that draws the the text label, bold, italic, font name

The second chart, shows the separate "modules" or classes that do that separatly:

```
................................................................................
..+--------------------------------+............................................
..|        GraphicObjectClass      |............................................
..+--------------------------------+............................................
..| [+]  void Draw(); <<virtual>>  |............................................
..+---------------*----------------+............................................
..................|.............................................................
..................^.............................................................
................./.\............................................................
................/...\...........................................................
.............../--+--\..........................................................
..................|.............................................................
..+---------------*----------------+.../|...+--------------------------------+..
..|      ButtonComponentClass      |../.|...|      SolidColorButtonClass     |..
..+--------------------------------+-<..|-*.+--------------------------------+..
..| [+]  void Draw(); <<virtual>>  |..\.|.|.| [+]  void Draw(); <<override>> |..
..+--------------------------------+...\|.|.+--------------------------------+..    
..........................................|.....................................
..........................................|.+--------------------------------+..
..........................................|.|       LabeledButtonClass       |..
..........................................|.+--------------------------------+..
..........................................*-* [+]  void Draw(); <<override>> |..
..........................................|.+--------------------------------+..
..........................................|.....................................
..........................................|.+--------------------------------+..
..........................................|.|        BorderButtonClass       |..
..........................................|.+--------------------------------+..
..........................................*-* [+]  void Draw(); <<override>> |..
............................................+--------------------------------+..
................................................................................
```

Let's integrate the components to the button, note that I make a distinct chart for inheritance association, from other associations.

```
.......................................................................................
.+--------------------------------------------+.....+--------------------------------+.
.|              CompositeButtonClass          |.....|      SolidColorButtonClass     |.
.+--------------------------------------------+.....+--------------------------------+.
.| [+] ButtonComponentClass* Background       *-----* [+]  void Draw(); <<override>> |.
.|                                            |.....+--------------------------------+.
.| [+] ButtonComponentClass* Border           *---*....................................
.|                                            |...|.+--------------------------------+.
.| [+] ButtonComponentClass* Label            *-*.|.|       LabeledButtonClass       |.
.+--------------------------------------------+.|.|.+--------------------------------+.
.| [+] void Draw();               <<virtual>> |.|.+-* [+]  void Draw(); <<override>> |.
.+--------------------------------------------+.|...+--------------------------------+.
................................................|......................................
................................................|...+--------------------------------+.
................................................|...|        BorderButtonClass       |.
................................................|...+--------------------------------+.
................................................*---* [+]  void Draw(); <<override>> |.
....................................................+--------------------------------+.
.......................................................................................
```

Now, you'll have a button class that will "delegate" the "draw" functuonality to members or items. Let's show the main class, by itself, first.

```
virtual /* override */ void CompositeButtonClass::Draw()
{
   // [Background Draw]     
   this->Background->Draw();

   // [Border Draw]
   this->Border->Draw();

   // [Label Draw]
   this->Label->Draw();
}
```

Just a suggestion.

Cheers.